# How to combine Graph API field expansions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using this syntax to query multiple metrics

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/69999732748?fields=insights.metric(page_fan_adds_unique,page_fan_adds,page_fan_adds_by_paid_non_paid_unique)&access_token=XYZ&period=day&since=2015-08-12&until=2015-08-13

I always get data for the last three days regardness of the values of the since and until parameters

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/69999732748/insights/page_fan_adds_unique?period=day&access_token=XYZ&since=2015-09-10&until=2015-09-11

If I ask for a single metric, then the date parameters have effect.

Is there a different syntax for requesting multiple insights metrics which  will accept the date parameters?

Comment: That first API call doesn't look right to me: You should be using `insights` as a Graph API edge, and not as a field (which is what you are doing). Please check if doing that so will yield different results.

Comment: My query works fine - besides ignoring the date. I use the insights.metrics() pattern to query more than one insight metric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
curl -G \
-d "access_token=PAGE_TOKEN" \
-d "fields=insights.metric(page_fan_adds_unique,page_fan_adds,page_fan_adds_by_paid_non_paid_unique).since(2015-08-12).until(2015-08-13).period(day)" \
-d "pretty=1" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me"
```

You are requesting the page's `insights` as a field. This field contains a list of results in a `data` array (`insights.data`), and you want to filter this array.

The way to do that is by chaining parameterizations to the requested `insights` field like so:

```
fields=insights
  .filter1(params)
  .filter2(params)
  .filter3(params)
```

Each `.filterX(params)` will be applied to the particular field that precedes it.
I've added newlines and indentation for clarity, but in your actual request you'd chain them all in a single line, without spaces.

Comment: Cool! So where would I find that documented?

Comment: One thing I'm still trying to clear up is are there any advantages/disadvantages when comparing these two approaches to getting insights

.../fields=insights.metric(page_fan_adds_unique,page_fan_adds).since(2015-08-12).until(2015-08-13).period(day)

vs

.../insights/page_fan_adds_unique,page_fan_adds?period=day&since=2015-09-12&until=2015-09-13

I know that with the first that I could request additional non-insights fields. But if I'm just getting insights, is there really any difference?

Comment: This isn't documented and therefor not supported. The advantage of the former is that for as long as this works you can use this to get all kinds of insights with a single request, without having to use a batch requests. The advantage of the latter is that it is officially supported, so if it breaks you can file a bug about it with Facebook. I got the idea of trying this while reading through ["Using the Graph API"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5)